# Установка Visual Studio 2019

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Думаю, новости о [Visual Studio 2019](https://habr.com/ru/company/jugru/blog/446534/) знают все. Но кто рассказал бы, как ее установить, если на машине стоит Visual Studio 2017? Ставить две визуалы для меня слишком большая роскошь - а потому как **заменить** одну на другую максимально аккуратно?

Я ждал, что она пойдет как обновление, но если я правильно понял - этого не будет..

Comment: Если в 2017 до сих пор баг на баге, могу себе представить что творится в 2019, да еще и в пререлизе.

Comment: А что все же мешает поставить их обе?

Comment: Я помню как обновлял 2015 до 2017. В общем сработало - сносим ОС и ставим всё заново. То же самое - с Автокадом 2015 -> 2018.

Comment: @NewView Личные соображения :)

Comment: @freim Готовлю телегу зимой.